# Long legged swing verses "Scrunch and Punch" method in the vault

Tags: technique, track-and-field

I pole vaulted in high school and I originally learned to keep a long trail leg throughout the swing and into inversion; however, I've seen many vaulters have quite a bit of success by instead pulling their leg in, holding to load the pole, then extending into inversion. I personally still like a long trail leg because I feel it promotes a good follow through into complete and straight inversion. I don't really see anything wrong with the "Scrunch-and-punch" version though, so I thought I'd get some opinions. Ideas?